# What is the standard de facto unit test framework for Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, unit-test

I am new to Postgres and as I am about to start writing more and more code with it (script with procedures, etc.) I am wondering what is the "standard de facto" (more used, bigger community, open source, etc) unit test framework for it. Googling I have found a few options. Is PgTap the right choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## pgTAP

pgTAP is the only I know that is ever even talked about.

> pgTAP is a suite of database functions that make it easy to write TAP-emitting unit tests in psql scripts or xUnit-style test functions.

- [github](https://github.com/theory/pgtap)
- [web](http://pgtap.org/)
- [pgxn](https://pgxn.org/dist/pgtap/)